# Googletest: combine tests in a testsuite

Tags: googletest

I am trying googletest.

Previously i have been using Boost test and i have been using the macro BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE to group my tests into a Testsuite.

This makes the junit reports much more readable.

I have not found a hint how to do this or something similar in googletest. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the first parameter of the call to TEST() or TEST_F() as sort of a "test suite" identifier, like this:

```
TEST(TestSuiteName, shouldExpectTrue) {
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}

TEST(TestSuiteName, shouldExpectFalse) {
    EXPECT_FALSE(false);
}
```

Of course, when using a fixture class with TEST_F(), your TestSuiteName will need to match the name of your fixture class, so it will be necessary to create a separate fixture class for each test suite.

There is no way that I know of to break the test suites into sub-suites or anything like that, but of course you could always run your tests multiple times using the --gtest_filter="someFilter" option if you wanted to clean up your output.